# Open Access file with button click

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

Is it possible to open my Microsoft Access file with just a button click event?

The tutorials I read online has to go through `OpenFileDialog` but I do not want that. I want to open the file directly with a click of a button.

File Location: `C:\Users\User\Documents\MedicalRecord.accdb`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Process.Start()`, it's the same thing as double-clicking your file directly.

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Process.Start(@"C:\Users\User\Documents\MedicalRecord.accdb");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible, instead of using open file dialog's file name, use the file location you want